# <img src="image_not_found.jpg" onError="this.style.display = 'none';" alt="" /> -not working in chrome

Tags: javascript, html

```
<img src="image_not_found.jpg" onError="this.style.display = 'none';" alt="" />
```

The above code does not work in chrome, after deleting still shows image not found. But it works in firefox, what else should i add to make it work in chrome. Mine is a php website

Comment: Are you sure it works in FF? FF hides not-found images by default anyway, if they don't have `alt` attribute or it's empty.

Comment: The result should be nothing, which is what I'm getting in Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/L8xvE/

Comment: @Teemu There isn't one.

Comment: <img class="example-image" src="../<?php echo $ongoing_gal_home[$i]['thumb']; ?>" onError="this.style.display = 'none';" alt="" /></a> still it shows image not found???

Comment: Looks like your problem can't be reproduced, can you add a link to the page? @Rhyono I'm sorry, ofcourse there's not a problem. Actually I was a little bit hasty, thinking OP has posted the comment with fiddle link : ).

Comment: You've the `onerror`s attached to `a` elements instead of `img` elements on your page...

Answer (score 4):

Try small letters:

```
onerror="this.style.display = 'none'"
```

Answer (score -1):

This might be of help if you want to style 'onerror' or broken images. It really resolved an issue I battled with for a while.

```
<img src="/path/toimage" alt="my image" onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src='/broken-img.svg';this.classList.add('broken-img');">
```